# Overloading generic and void Task type

Tags: c#, task, overloading, extension-methods

I made this hacky workaround to add pre/post logging to some of my async api calls.

Is there a more concise/better way of writing the overload for void Task?

Is there something wrong in general with this approach?  Any suggested changes?

```
public static Task<TResult> LogAsyncTask<TResult>
(this Task<TResult> task, string messageTemplate, 
   LogEventLevel level = LogEventLevel.Information)
{
  Log.Write(level, "Async Starting: " + messageTemplate);
  return task.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
  {
    var result = antecedent.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Log.Write(level, "Async Finished: " + messageTemplate);
    return result;
  });
}

public static Task<object> LogAsyncTask
(this Task task, string messageTemplate, 
   LogEventLevel level = LogEventLevel.Information)
 => Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    return null;
  }).LogAsyncTask(messageTemplate, level);
```

Here's how you call it:

```
await apiClient.MySoapMethodAsync().LogAsyncTask("Doing MySoapMethod...");
```

Comment: The obvious issue I see with this code is it must, by its nature, *lie*. If you're calling a method with a hot task (which your code assumes since it only calls `ContinueWith` and not `Start`) then by the time you output "Starting", the task has already started and may even in fact have already finished.

Comment: Fildor, it uses serilog. Damien, yeah I'm fine with that, this is mainly for soap calls that could end up taking 1+ seconds, just to track any long running calls. I understand the log line could get called after the method starts, but usually not that long after as to materially affect the timing in our case.

Comment: Yes, I thought I had seen a syntax error, but it was my old dirty eyes ... Do you only want to measure roundtrip-times or do you want to also insert some sort of time-out functionality later?

Comment: This is purely for measurement. I even use awaiter so that it will rethrow any error.

Answer (score 0):

As Damien correctly pointed out, your code has a problem where it will only log "Async Starting" (and presumably start the timer) *after* the synchronous portion of the async method has completed (and returned a task). A proper solution would use an aspect-oriented framework like Fody or PostSharp; you can get started with [my AsyncDiagnostics project](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncDiagnostics), which does something very similar.

If you do keep your current approach, you shouldn't use [`ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html) or [`StartNew`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html). Also, you should ensure the final log is written regardless of exceptions:

```
public static async Task<TResult> LogAsyncTask<TResult>(
    this Task<TResult> task, string messageTemplate,
    LogEventLevel level = LogEventLevel.Information)
{
  Log.Write(level, "Async Starting: " + messageTemplate);
  try
  {
    return await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
  finally
  {
    Log.Write(level, "Async Finished: " + messageTemplate);
  }
}

public static Task LogAsyncTask(
    this Task task, string messageTemplate, 
    LogEventLevel level = LogEventLevel.Information)
{
  return LogAsyncTask<object>(async () =>
  {
    await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    return null;
  }, messageTemplate, level);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers/comments have mentioned, you have a core problem with your current code in that you don't indicate that it's starting until some time after it has been started, possibly even after it has finished.  There is a simple solution though, and that's to accept a method that returns a `Task`, rather than the `Task` itself, such that calling the method starts the asynchronous operation.

As Stephen has noted, you really shouldn't be using `ContinueWith` here.  It's hard to get the right semantics for propagating the task's state (you didn't quite get it right) and using `await` is just *far* easier and clearer.

Note that trying to implement one method in terms of the other (you can implement either in terms of the other) isn't really worth the effort here.  Both methods are just *so* simple, that it's just as easy to implement correctly from scratch for the generic and non-generic version as it is to call the other overload, if not even easier, so I wouldn't bother.  Additionally, if you're calling a method like this often (which it seems like you would be) the very small performance benefit of not calling unnecessary code is likely a worthwhile benefit, given the costs are so low.

```
public static async Task<TResult> LogAsyncTask<TResult>(
    Func<Task<TResult>> asyncMethod, string messageTemplate,
    LogEventLevel level = LogEventLevel.Information)
{
    Log.Write(level, "Async Starting: " + messageTemplate);
    try
    {
        return await asyncMethod().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.Write(level, "Async Finished: " + messageTemplate);
    }
}

public static async Task LogAsyncTask(
    Func<Task> asyncMethod, string messageTemplate,
    LogEventLevel level = LogEventLevel.Information)
{
    Log.Write(level, "Async Starting: " + messageTemplate);
    try
    {
        await asyncMethod().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.Write(level, "Async Finished: " + messageTemplate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea looks interesting.
You could also have a look at Aspect Oriented Programming to solve your problem.
I tried to do something very similar.

Look at the article [Aspect-Oriented Programming : Aspect-Oriented Programming with the RealProxy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx) and then look at my article [Aspect Oriented Programming in C# with RealProxy](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1204871/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-in-Csharp-with-RealPro) how to fix example from the first article to handle Task result. Even if you decide not to use AOP you can adopt my code from the second article to your solution.